# Android/Kotlin: How to get a function in a class that execute a SQL query on a specific SQLite database name?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, factory, sqliteopenhelper

I have two different SQLite in my App. I would like to get a method that execute a SQL query on a specific SQLite database name but I don't know how to do a "dynamic factory database name"?

That code works well but only if I use always the same DB in the **companion Object** section.

```
  class MyDBHandler(context: Context, name: String?,
                      factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version: Int) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION) 
{
        override fun methodToSelectData(strQuery: String, dataBase: String)
{

}
        companion object {

            private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
            private val DATABASE_NAME = "xxx.db"
        }
}
```

Example 1: **methodToSelectData("Select * From table_X", "database1.db")**
Example 2: **methodToSelectData("Select * From table_Y", "database2.db")**
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you have 2 databases and only 1 SQLiteOpenHelper class? If so, this is wrong. You must create 1 class for each database.

Comment: @forpas Really? There is no way to have one class for 2 databases in Android? Because I do it in iOS and it works...

Comment: The constructor of the class takes the name of the database as an argument. This class manages 1 database only. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: @forpas Thanks, so I will create two classes for each database, and one that will manage the two classes in function of the database chosed by the user...

Comment: For sure 2 SQLiteOpenHelper classes and about the method, it must be in a separate class or utility file.